# Pandas compare 1 columns values to another dataframe column, find matching rows

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a database that I am bringing in a SQL table of events and alarms (df1), and I have a txt file of alarm codes and properties (df2) to watch for. Want to use 1 columns values from df2 that each value needs cross checked against an entire column values in df1, and output the entire rows of any that match into another dataframe df3.

```
df1     A   B   C   D
0     100  20   1   1
1     101  30   1   1
2     102  21   2   3
3     103  15   2   3
4     104  40   2   3

df2     0   1   2   3   4
0      21   2   2   3   3
1      40   0 NaN NaN NaN
```

Output entire rows from df1 that column B match with any of df2 column 0 values into df3.

```
df3     A   B   C   D
0     102  21   2   3
1     104  40   2   3
```

I was able to get single results using:

```
df1[df1['B'] == df2.iloc[0,0]]
```

But I need something that will do this on a larger scale.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Method 1: `merge`

Use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), on `B` and `0`. Then select only the `df1` columns

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='B', right_on='0')[df1.columns]

     A   B  C  D
0  102  21  2  3
1  104  40  2  3
```

## Method 2: `loc`

Alternatively use `loc` to find rows in `df1` where `B` has a match in `df2` column `0` using [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df1.loc[df1.B.isin(df2['0'])]

     A   B  C  D
2  102  21  2  3
4  104  40  2  3
```